# Add an addEventListner on a class remove

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I made some fandeIn and fadeOut codes to an exercise.
I'm trying to remove the setTimeout() on the fadeIn().
Like using an addEventListner maybe, but there is no transition on .displayNone.

On the MDN I just found transitions interacting with EventListner.

```js
function fadeOut(disable) {
    disable.classList.remove('visible');
    disable.classList.add('hidden');
    disable.addEventListener('transitionend', () => disable.classList.add('displayNone'));
};

function fadein(enable, timer) {
    if (!timer) timer = 350;
    enable.classList.remove('displayNone');
    setTimeout(function () {
        enable.classList.remove('hidden');
        enable.classList.add('visible');
    }, timer);
};
```

```css
.displayNone {
    display: none;
}

.visible {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1.5s linear;
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s 350ms, opacity 350ms, display 350ms linear;
}
```

P.S.: This works good, I'm just trying another way to make it works too.

Comment: Why do you need another way when this one's working? It's not that it's dirty code or anything.

Comment: Nothing special, just trying something more organic. I'm new at coding. Studying for now

Comment: Seems perfectly organic to me. You *could* use CSS transition delays, but it doesn't matter that much.

Comment: Oh thanks! I'm happy to know it's a clean code. I'll find something about delay transition later. Thanks again

Comment: @asaks- What do you mean by “organic”? “Organic” isn’t a programming term. What (objective) criteria are you looking for? What kind of answers are you looking for? What are the deficiencies in the current code? What is your question? Stack Overflow questions should be [specific and answerable](/help/dont-ask), and not just “Does anyone have any random ideas when looking at this code?”.

Comment: @SebastianSimon hmm... right, I',m not explained correctly. To the fadeOut works, it don't depends to a timer to start any event on the site. The last step stars when the previous ended. But the fadeIn not. I set a timer to start the transitions event presuming the time first one ends. In my POV, not the best solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout` method returns a timeout descriptor/id (actually just an integer). You may use it to remove the timeout later:

```
// setting timeout
var timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){}, 5000);
window.clearTimeout( timeout )
```

Comment: And why would this be necessary in the user's context?

Comment: Hm.. "I'm trying to remove the setTimeout() on the fadeIn()". Did I get it wrong?

Comment: @Jared Sorry, it's my fault. I',m not explained correctly. To the fadeOut works, it don't depends to a timer to start any event on the site. The last step stars when the previous ended. But the fadeIn not. I set a timer to start the transitions event presuming the time first one ends. In my POV, not the best solution, but I don't have anther one for now.